# How to use File History with Recovery partition?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, backup, file-history, recovery-partition

I formatted the recovery partition right after installing Windows 8.

I'm curious as to why File history only allow the use of external HDD. Instead of using the Recovery Partition. I can't find a way to use it. I decided to use it exclusively for Restore Points.

Is there any way to make the Recovery Partition exclusively for the use of File History?

Or should I use 3rd Party programs instead, (Easeus Todo Backup, Macrium Reflect, etc)?

Comment: File History [does not allow](http://superuser.com/questions/491377/queries-related-to-the-new-windows-8-file-history-feature) you to specify a partition on the system drive to store history in.

Answer (score 0):

good. we must first understand that the recovery partition has a specific objective which is Recovering from a failure that prevents booting OS . If your computer came with a recovery partition, it is better not to change it. since this partition you could serve in the future (Windows 8 may even back up such partition on a USB flash)

File History only Allows you to save backup disk not be the OS, whether internal or external. This protects you in case of failure of your hard drive where you have Windows, your files will be safe

but if you want to use File History on your own hard drive could use another strategy. which is by using Virtual Hard Disks (VHD)

http://mypersonalnerd.blogspot.mx/2012/10/windows-8-enabling-file-history-on.html